# Matlab: Using Accumarray

Tags: arrays, matlab, accumulate

If I have a column of dates and a corresponding column of volume data, like this:

```
31,3
31,2
31,1
31,5
07,2
07,3
07,4
07,2
07,3
07,5
07,3
07,1
07,1
07,2
07,3
30,5
06,4
```

I want to add up the data in the right hand column, for each date. If I use accumarray like this:

```
orgSumVinDay=accumarray(dayIdx,vv); 
k=orgSumVinDay==0;
SumVininDay=orgSumVinDay;
SumVinDay(k)=[]
```

It works; I get:

```
11
29
 5
 4
```

which is correct because on the 31st, there were `3+2+1+5=11`, etc.

However, I want to get a column showing the cumulative addition within each day, so that it looks like:

```
 3
 5
 6
11 
 2
 4
 9
11
14
19
22
23
24
26
29
 5
 4
```

and I'm not sure how to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot check it right now but I believe you should be able to do it with `accumarray (..., [], @cumsum)`. The last parameter will replace the default function `sum` with `cumsum`.

Comment: Strange, `accumarray(dayStr,minuteVolumes, [],@cumsum)` gives the error "The function 'cumsum' returned a non-scalar value." But if I use a different function, like `@max` for example, the results are correct.

Comment: This works! `cell2mat(accumarray(dayStr,minuteVolumes,[],@(x){cumsum(x)}));` Thanks!